# how to setup accounts for reporting services to view by users?

Tags: reporting-services

I can view my reports on my p.c but on the other users,it only show plain SQL Server Reporting Services Home only.

Comment: Where are your reports? Is everybody using the same url (and that url doesn't involve *localhost* or *127.0.0.1*)? Have you added the other users to the *Browser* role?

Comment: yes,i just added them but this error now occurs:

is Error Occurs. An error occurred during client rendering. An error has occurred during report processing. Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'. For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://reportserver/reports page, go to properties tab->security->new role assignment->Add everyone or any user account that you would like to add.

Browser permission is the basic permission to view reports. And all sub report folder will inherit this permission

Comment: This Error Occurs.
An error occurred during client rendering.
An error has occurred during report processing.
Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'.
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Comment: Please check the report log on your report server. It seems the connection failed due to incorrect connection. The location of the log is usually C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER2008\Reporting Services\LogFiles. Or you can also enable remote errors just as error message shows. I guess there might be permission related error message

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the credentials needed to access your datasource are stored properly. Or, if you're using integrated security, make sure more than just your account (The one that's working on your PC) has permission.

It's also a good idea to do exactly what the message is saying: Enable remote errors. That way you'll see the full error message that your users are getting.